# What would be an example of a mapping $m$ which satisfies all properties of a measure/outer-measure except well-definedness?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, outer-measure

So far my experience has been that in algebra classes the well-definedness of a function has been stressed in most of the exercises while in analysis/measure theory there are usually so many details to talk about that well-definedness is not usually considered that much. Therefore I was wondering what would be a diabolic example of a mapping $m$ which satisfies all properties of a measure/outer-measure except the well-definedness.

That is, if you were given the task: "Prove or disprove: $m$ is a measure/an outer-measure on the set $X$", then you could show that 1.) $m:2^X\to [0, \infty]$, 2.) $m(\varnothing) = 0$, 3.) $A\subset B \subset X\implies m(A)\leq m(B)$ and 4.) $m\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i\right)\leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty m\left(A_i\right)$ but for some $A = B \subset X: m(A) \neq m(B)$ making it impossible for $m$ to be a measure as it is not a function.

Comment: A not well-defined object cannot satisfy any properties, since it is not a well-defined object.

Comment: @PhoemueX Interesting! Why is this the case?

Comment: If $m(A)$ can be lots of numbers, what does the statement "$m(A)\leq m(B)$" mean?  True for one output?  True for all?  Something else?

Comment: One example is $m(A) =$

Comment: @Michael What does $-$ mean in this context?

Comment: @JasonDeVito That is a good question. I suppose that the properties should hold e.g. when the inputs are represented in a certain way. E.g. $f\left(\frac{n}{m}\right) = n$ is not well-defined for general $\frac{n}{m}$ as $f\left(\frac{1}{1}\right) = 1 \neq 2 = f\left(\frac{2}{2}\right)$. But the function is well-defined if we require that $\mathrm{gcd}(n, m) = 1$. So a naive student may implicitly assume that $n$ and $m$ satisfy $\mathrm{gcd}(n, m) =1$ and therefore deem $f$ to be well-defined. What I am looking for is an analogue to this kind of situation with measures.

Comment: @SickSeries : It was not well defined. =) Note that "well defined" just means that a stated definition makes sense. A definition that does not make sense is one that implicitly requires some property to be true that may not always be true. For example, if $A$ is a real-valued square matrix I cannot really define $\lambda(A)$ as the largest eigenvalue of $A$ (because $A$ may not have any eigenvalues or may have complex-valued ones). However $\lambda(A)$ is "well defined" if I assume $A$ is symmetric (since then it can be proven that eigenvalues exist and all are real).

Comment: In terms of your 4 properties of the last paragraph of the question: Property 1 already states that $m$ is a function. Indeed, $m:2^X\rightarrow[0,\infty]$ means that "$m$ is a function from the set $2^X$ to the set $[0,\infty]$." So the example you are looking for does not make sense (a function that is not a function).  So my nonsense answer $m(A)=$ can be argued as being reasonable in a world where things do not make sense.